# How to get last indexed record in Solr?

Tags: java, apache, solr, indexing, solrj

I want to know how to get/search last indexed record in Apache Solr..?

When the existing record is updated then it goes to end of all the records...so I want to get that last indexed record.

thanks..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could add a 'timestamp' field to your Solr schema that puts the current date/time into the record when it is added.

```
<field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
```

Then, do a sort in descending order by this field and the first record will be the latest one. A query like this should do it:-

http://localhost:8080/solr/core-name/select/q=*%3A*&start=0&rows=1&sort=timestamp+desc

Comment: Is there no other way...? because I have to add field in Solr indexing then...
thanks for reply...

Comment: I believe this to be most reliable way to do this, as the timestamp field will be added by Solr and is guaranteed to be accurate. You could go with @parvin's answer, but that would assume that your docid field is sequential and can be sorted.

Answer (score 9):

You can sort the documents by the indexed order using the following query.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&sort=_docid_ asc

or 

http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&sort=_docid_ desc
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.

Comment: Is it safe to count on docid cross merges? see http://osdir.com/ml/solr-user.lucene.apache.org/2011-12/msg01178.html

Comment: dont use _docid_ because it changing see that response to understand  http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Get-DocID-after-Document-insert-td556278.html

Comment: For me this is not the best way to get the desire result: `q*:*` tells solr to search in every record you have in index. In my case, with over 30 millions stored records the response took about 10 seconds to be return, even if I add `rows=1`. Is there an efficient way to get the last record?