# Add document insert timestamp to all documents

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 5.3.1 in schemaless mode. The server is running.

I can [add a `timestamp` field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12346434/953327) to my managed-schema

```
<field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
```

By POST'ing to the `/schema` endpoint.

That's fine. But afterwards, Solr doesn't automatically add the field to my documents when they are being inserted.

Do I need to restart?

Do I have to index the document with `timestamp` specified but blank?

Is there a way to automatically add it to all documents regardless of if it has a `timestamp` attribute?

Comment: The `default` value should be invoked (it used to be, at least) for timestamp fields as well. Do you get a value if you provide a timestamp in the correct format as the default value?

Comment: @MatsLindh Actually it's not doing anything with the new field. I tried adding a document with a blank `timestamp`, nothing. If I add a document with a valid timestamp, it does add it to the index. I updated the question to clarify I am adding the field to a running Solr, would that change things?

Comment: Most changes used to require a core reload, but I'm not sure about how the managed schema changes things. Can you see the field if you show the current schema under the admin interface?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes it shows up in the admin interface. I think I probably need to restart the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A restart of the Solr Server was required. After restarting, all documents added included the new `timestamp` field.

Comment: Do we still need to restart the Solr Server in the Solr version 6.6.1 ? Please share

Comment: @Karan I have not tested on 6.6.1 but my guess would be yes it is still needed. There shouldn't be much risk in just trying it without a restart though and seeing if your docs get inserted with the timestamp.

Comment: There is only need to reload the core after the schema change and no need to restart the Solr server. I tried in the 6.6.1 version.

Comment: As @Karan said, a reload of the core also works `curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=your-core"`